# Use returned server parameter to display data

Tags: datatables

I tried to use jQuery DataTables. Before I used bootstrap table.
On the server, I use spring boot, spring data with paging.

```html
   <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>memberId</th>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>phone1</th>
                <th>phone2</th>
                <th>email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>  
    </table>
```

```js
$('#example').DataTable({
            "processing": "true",
            "serverSide": "true",
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/rest/members",
                "data": function (d) {
                    return {
                        search: d.search.value,
                        page: d.start,
                        size: d.length
                    }

                },
                dataFilter: function (data) {
                    var json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    json.recordsTotal = json.totalElements;
                    json.data = json.content;
                    return JSON.stringify(json); // return JSON string
                }

            }
        });
```

With value returned by server, I try to display data. Actually, nothing is displayed

```js
{  
   "content":[  
      {  
         "memberId":1,
         "name":"bob",
         "phone1": "450",
         "phone2": "1",
         "email": "test"
      },
      {  
         "memberId":2,
         "name":"robert"
         "phone1": "2323",
         "phone2": "2",
         "email": "test"
      }
   ],
   "last":true,
   "totalElements":27,
   "totalPages":1,
   "sort":null,
   "numberOfElements":27,
   "first":true,
   "size":100,
   "number":0
}
```

Edit

DataTables warning: table id=example - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few issues

1. The sample JSON is not valid, you have trailing commas
2. The ajax data callback is called `dataSrc`, not `dataFilter`
3. You do not need to parse `data`, JSON is already the accepted dataType
4. Returning `data` as string where an array is expected will raise an error
5. A working callback could look this

```js
    dataSrc: function(data) {
       data.recordsTotal = data.totalElements;
       data.data = data.content;
       return data.data
    }
```

demo based on the JSON above -> **http://jsfiddle.net/sx3py6fg/**

Comment: @roberttrudel, now there is missing a comma :) See update, have made a small fiddle - there is really not much to add.